# Inline css background not showing on Chrome/Safari/IE but it works on Mozilla Firefox

Tags: html, css, magento

I have a CSS issue:

I created this select with 3 options:(it can be found here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rcHMc/6/))

```
<select id="currency_dropdown_select" name="currency">
    <option class="currency_dropdown_option" style="background:url('http://www.jorggray.co.uk/skin/frontend/default/luxury/images/flags/img-GBP.jpg');" value="GBP" selected="selected"></option>

    <option class="currency_dropdown_option" style="background: url('http://www.jorggray.co.uk/skin/frontend/default/luxury/images/flags/img-EUR.jpg');" value="EUR"></option>

    <option class="currency_dropdown_option" style="background:url('http://www.jorggray.co.uk/skin/frontend/default/luxury/images/flags/img-USD.jpg');" value="USD"></option>
</select>
```

I already tried a lot of changes to solve this issue but any known solutions isn't working.
There is not an adblock block because its disabled.

tried using background-image but without result.

Any idea?

Comment: I checked each one of the URL's, everyone gave 404.

Comment: I agree with @fizzydrink

Comment: @fizzydrink they are working for me...what is happening here?!!?

Comment: You might have a local cached copy in your browser. Try clearing temporary files and restarting your browser.

Comment: For me, none of the img-GBP or img-EUR or img-USD are showing up. Each one is 404 - Not found

Comment: @fizzydrink check the site. http://www.jorggray.co.uk . the dropdown is in upper left corner. Cache is cleaned and still showing my images.

Answer (score 3):

`OPTION` tags don't fully support CSS since they are OS-level controls. Each system and browser renders them differently.

If you want backgrounds on a drop-down you're better off using a JavaScript-based one that turns an unordered list into a drop-down, such as the one in jQuery UI or Twitter Bootstrap.